# Sorting grouped objects

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of objects. Each object has two attributes: `DispName` and `MachID`. `DispName` can either start with `theoretical` or be something else.

I need to sort this list in the following way:

- first alphabetically per `MachID`.

  - within each `MachID` subgroup first the object where the name starts with `theoretical`
  - then the other objects sorted alphabetically.

This is the code I have now, which works and produces the required output, but I was wondering if I could write this more pythonic, maybe making use of `groupby`? (My excuses for the camelCasing).

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
from operator import attrgetter

Mapping = namedtuple('Mapping', ['DispName', 'MachID'])

objectList = [Mapping('map 2 (MT1)', 'MT1'),
          Mapping('theoretical (MT1)', 'MT1'),
          Mapping('map 3 (MT2)', 'MT2'),
          Mapping('theoretical (MT2)', 'MT2'),
          Mapping('map 1 (MT1)', 'MT1'),
          Mapping('map 2 (MT2)', 'MT2')]

def complexSort(objectList):
    objectDict = defaultdict(list)
    sortedMappingList = []
    # group by machine ID 
    for obj in objectList:
        objectDict[obj.MachID].append(obj)
    # loop over the mappings sorted alphabetically by machine ID
    for machID in sorted(objectDict.keys()):
        mappings = objectDict[machID]
        nonTheoreticalMappings = []
        for mapping in mappings:
            if mapping.DispName.startswith('theoretical'):
                # if we encounter the theoretical mapping, add it first
                sortedMappingList.append(mapping)
            else:
                # gather the other mappings in a sublist
                nonTheoreticalMappings.append(mapping)
        # and add that sublist sorted alphabetically
        sortedMappingList.extend(sorted(nonTheoreticalMappings, 
                                     key=attrgetter('DispName')))           
    return sortedMappingList

for mapping in complexSort(objectList):
    print mapping.DispName
```

Produces:

```
theoretical (MT1)
map 1 (MT1)
map 2 (MT1)
theoretical (MT2)
map 2 (MT2)
map 3 (MT2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import collections 
import operator
import itertools as IT

Mapping = collections.namedtuple('Mapping', ['DispName', 'MachID'])

objectList = [Mapping('map 2 (MT1)', 'MT1'),
          Mapping('theoretical (MT1)', 'MT1'),
          Mapping('map 3 (MT2)', 'MT2'),
          Mapping('theoretical (MT2)', 'MT2'),
          Mapping('map 1 (MT1)', 'MT1'),
          Mapping('map 2 (MT2)', 'MT2')]

sortedMappingList = sorted(objectList,
             key=lambda mapping:
                            (mapping.MachID,
                             not mapping.DispName.startswith('theoretical'),
                             mapping.DispName))

for key, group in IT.groupby(sortedMappingList, key=operator.attrgetter('MachID')):
    for g in group:
        print(g.DispName)
```

yields

```
theoretical (MT1)
map 1 (MT1)
map 2 (MT1)
theoretical (MT2)
map 2 (MT2)
map 3 (MT2)
```

There is an excellent tutorial on [How to sort using key functions](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting), here.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `sorted` with a `key` that produces the order you want. Since tuples are ordered lexicographically, a `key` that produces tuples should work pretty well.

```
def sort_key(thing):
    return (thing.MachID, not thing.DispName.startswith('theoretical'))

sorted(objectList, key=sort_key) # returns a list sorted the way you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom comparator to describe how two Mappings should be ordered with respect to one another. This is somewhat cleaner than your `complexSort`, since the function's only responsibility is comparing two objects, and leaves the actual sorting to Python.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Mapping = namedtuple('Mapping', ['DispName', 'MachID'])


def cmp_Mapping(a,b):
    #first, sort alphabetically by MachID
    if a.MachID != b.MachID:
        return cmp(a.MachID, b.MachID)
    else:
        #if MachIDs match, and one starts with "theoretical", it should go first.
        if a.DispName.startswith("theoretical") and not b.DispName.startswith("theoretical"):
            return -1
        elif b.DispName.startswith("theoretical") and not a.DispName.startswith("theoretical"):
            return 1
        #everything else is ordered alphabetically.
        else:
            return cmp(a.DispName, b.DispName)

objectList = [Mapping('map 2 (MT1)', 'MT1'),
          Mapping('theoretical (MT1)', 'MT1'),
          Mapping('map 3 (MT2)', 'MT2'),
          Mapping('theoretical (MT2)', 'MT2'),
          Mapping('map 1 (MT1)', 'MT1'),
          Mapping('map 2 (MT2)', 'MT2')]

for mapping in sorted(objectList, cmp = cmp_Mapping):
    print mapping.DispName
```

Result:

```
theoretical (MT1)
map 1 (MT1)
map 2 (MT1)
theoretical (MT2)
map 2 (MT2)
map 3 (MT2)
```